# Create Query in Bigquery from firebase data

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I am working with Bigquery with data from firebase.
I would like to get events and others variable like country, traffic, etc.

I could get events with this code, but when I tried to add a new variable "user_dim.geo_info.country" I got a error: SELECT list expression references user_dim.geo_info.country which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [3:3]

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  user_dim.geo_info.country,
  event.name AS event_name,
  _TABLE_SUFFIX as day,
  COUNT(1) as users
FROM `project_new.app_events_*`, 
UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
GROUP BY event_name, day
```

Somebody Can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to add it to GROUP BY as below

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  user_dim.geo_info.country AS country,
  event.name AS event_name,
  _TABLE_SUFFIX AS day,
  COUNT(1) AS users
FROM `project_new.app_events_*`, 
UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
GROUP BY country, event_name, day
```